# What is the difference between auto-start and manual start in an A320?

Tags: jet-engine, airbus-a320

What is the difference between auto-start option and manual start in the Airbus A320?

Can you please explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Auto-Start option you just press the button, and wait until the engine starts. In manual option you need to monitor all parameters, you need to open valves manually, ignition manually etc and etc. You can check video for 100% understanding: